# streaming raspberry webcam to apache2

Tags: apache, raspberry-pi, webcam, motion

I'm trying to display in a webpage the content that is being recorded with a webcam connected to a raspberry pi model B. For this purpose, I have installed both apache2 and motion in my pi.

When I enter my pi's IP address and a port number (192.168.1.40:8081) in the browser, I'm able to see what's in front of my webcam. Now, I would like to use the webserver to display the streaming just by entering the IP address from the client's side (and a domain name and a DNS in the future).

To do so, I've tried the following html code in the index.html file that is shown by apache (I'm a real noob in html...), but doesn't work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<video width="640" height="480" controls>
 <source src="192.168.1.40:8081" type="video/mp4">
</video>

</body>
</html>
```

It would be very helpful if anybody could tell me how to display my cams content through the apache server.

Comment: Hi, It appears you may not need the index.html. You're trying to access webcam from any where, right?

Comment: That's right! I thought that the easiest way was to use a webserver to do so. What would you do?